# Storing User-Defined JavaScript Objects In LocalStorage and Retrieving Them As User Defined Object Types

Tags: javascript, json

I've been working on an application which involved localstorage.  I've got an array of `deck` type objects.  The deck object itself contains `card` type objects.  So after looking up on how to use localstorage to store objects, I came up across this SO post:

[Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

From what I've understood, localstorage stores data only as string, so my deck objects need be converted to a string using `JSON.stringify`.

However, when I retrieve the objects from localstorage using `JSON.parse`, I get an object which is not of my original user-defined type, i.e. of `deck` type.

My question is so: is there a way to retrieve my objects from localstorage as objects of their original type (deck type)?  Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the optional [reviver argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert them:

```
var json = '{"decks": [{"cards":[{"id": 1},{"id": 2},{"id": 3}],"id":3},{"cards":[{"id": 4},{"id": 5},{"id": 6}],"id":4}]}';

function Deck( cards, id ) {
    this.cards = cards;
    this.id = id;
}

function Card(id) {
    this.id = id;
}

var decks = JSON.parse(json, function(key, value ) {

    if( key === "decks" ) {
        return value.map( function(deck) {
            return new Deck( deck.cards, deck.id );
        });
    }
    else if( key === "cards" ) {
        return value.map( function( card ) {
            return new Card( card.id );
        });
    }
    else {
        return value;
    }
}).decks;
```

Then doing:

```
console.log( decks )
```

Gives the following:

[image]